# json_encode outputs additional anchor tag

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I am using json_encode method to pass a string in a web service.

```
$send_message_code="";
$send_message_code .='<a href="http://www.epbitservices.com/webservices/R/1/" style="text-decoration:none;">';
$send_message_code .='http://www.epbitservices.com/webservices/E/epbitservices/';
$send_message_code .='</a>';
$x['myvar']= $send_message_code;        
$Text = json_encode($x);            
echo $Text;
```

Now, it outputs it as

```
{"myvar":"<a href="\&quot;http:\/\/www.epbitservices.com\/webservices\/R\/1\/\&quot;" style="\&quot;text-decoration:none;\&quot;">http:\/\/www.epbitservices.com\/webservices\/E\/epbitservices\/&lt;\/a&gt;"}</a>
```

that is with additional closing anchor tag at the end.

Comment: The extra `</a>` is outside of your json result.

Comment: why not adding th <a> tag on client side and just send the urls with json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [**`JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-unescaped-slashes) (Available since PHP 5.4.0) as second parameter for `json_encode` which will work for you.

```
$Text = json_encode($x, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

If you are running PHP < 5.4, you can use other [**`JSON_HEX_TAG*`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php#constant.json-hex-tag) constant.

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to change the apostrophe like this:

```
$send_message_code="<a href='http://www.epbitservices.com/webservices/R/1/' style='text-decoration:none;'>'http://www.epbitservices.com/webservices/E/epbitservices/</a>";
$x['myvar']= $send_message_code;        
$Text = json_encode($x);            
echo $Text;
```